# jquery - loading next elements not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many divs like this:

```
<div id="company_group_{{ $id }}_client" class="btn-group-vertical btn-block" role="group">
   <button class="btn btn-default update__remodal_btn">
      Ray Darrick Tromp
   </button>
   <button class="btn btn-default update__remodal_btn">
      Susan Stone
   </button>
    ...
   <div id="more">
      <a href="#" class="loadMore" data-list="company_group_{{ $id}}_client">
         Show more
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

And JS code:

```
$(function () {
    $(".update__remodal_btn").slice(0, 4).show();

    $(".loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var buttons = $("#"+ $(this).data('list'));

        buttons.slice(0, 4).slideDown();

        if (buttons.length == 0) {
            $(this).fadeOut('slow');
        } else {
            $(this).text("Show remaining ("+ buttons.length +")");
        }
    });
});
```

But this changing `Show remaining` always on `1` nothing more, why?
I need to show more (eg. next 5) elements in DIV in which I clicked `Show more...`

Comment: `$("#"+ $(this).data('list'));` is a DIV element, not buttons. Shouldn't it be `$("#"+ $(this).data('list')).find('button');` ?

Comment: Maybe you have same 'id' for all `<div>` blocks. Can you provide more html ?

Answer (score 0):

the problem in the code seems to be in the following:
 var buttons = $("#"+ $(this).data('list'));

I added more buttons, and used the following:
 $(".update__remodal_btn").slideDown(1000);
It showed me remaining buttons after clicking show more.

When I added more buttons its showed all of them where as per code it should show us only 4.
I first hide all of the buttons and than sliced to show 4 of them
Please follow the following plnkr link
https://plnkr.co/edit/cNoTanD2rQR6dczC25Bv?p=preview
I hope this helps`enter code here`